# Jpa Auditing dont save data in table auditing

Tags: jpa, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, audit, auditing

I have to implementes Auditing in my aplication.. i inserting this data correctly

[image]

but i want to save all atributter from my Entity , 
Exemple, name, epigrafe, .. and olthers.

I implemented the mothod but dosent work, just dont save the atributte..

lets see..

```
@Entity
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
@Table(name = "logradouros_historico", schema = "aud")
public class LogradourosHistorico {


        @Id
        @GeneratedValue
        private Long id;

        @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
        @JoinColumn(name = "id_logradouro")
        private Logradouros logradouro;


        @CreatedBy
        private String modificadoPor;


        @CreatedDate
        @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
        private Date modifiedDate = new Date();

        @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
        private Acoes acao;


        @Column(name = "nome")
        private String nome; //nome do logradouro

        public LogradourosHistorico() {
            super();

        }




        public LogradourosHistorico(Logradouros logradouro, String modificadoPor, 
                Acoes acao) {
            super();
            this.logradouro = logradouro;
            this.modificadoPor = modificadoPor;
            this.acao = acao;
        }
   //getters and setters
```

my class entityListner

```
public class LogradourosEntityListener {

    @PostPersist
    public void prePersist(Logradouros target) { 
        perform(target, Acoes.INSERTED);        
    }

    @PreUpdate
    public void preUpdate(Logradouros target) { 
         perform(target, Acoes.UPDATED);        
    }

    @PreRemove
    public void preRemove(Logradouros target) { 
        perform(target, Acoes.DELETED);

    }


    @Transactional()
    private void perform(Logradouros target, Acoes acao) {
        target.getNome();
        EntityManager entityManager = BeanUtil.getBean(EntityManager.class);
        entityManager.persist(new LogradourosHistorico(target, acao));

    } 
}

 my class Logradouros 

@Entity
@EntityListeners(LogradourosEntityListener.class)
@Table(name = "logradouros", schema = "glb",  uniqueConstraints= @UniqueConstraint(columnNames={"id_entidade", "idLogradouro"}))
public class Logradouros extends Auditable<String> implements Serializable  {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3703309412387185484L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int idLogradouro;

    @Column(name = "cep_geral")
    private String cepGeral;

    @Column(name = "epigrafe")
    private String epigrafe;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "nome")
    private String nome;

    @Column(name = "nome_exibicao")
    private String nomeExibicao;


    @JoinColumn(name = "id_entidade")
    @ManyToOne(/*cascade = CascadeType.ALL*/)
    private Entidades entidade;

    @NotNull
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_municipio")
    @ManyToOne(/*cascade = CascadeType.ALL*/)
    private Municipios municipio; 

    // gettrs and settrs
```

so what i did wrong because i cant get the `nome` of entity `Logradouros`

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel.. Use `hibernate-envers` which does exactly that out-of-the-box...

Comment: Maybe he isn't using Hibernate in the first place?

Comment: i has already implemented all methods of JPA